# estimating the population standard deviation from the sample standard deviation

Tags: standard-deviation

Is there a way to estimating the population standard deviation, $\sigma$, from the sample standard deviation, $s$, if the size of the finite population is $N$ and the size of the sample is $n$?

Is there expression true: $$ \sigma = s \cdot \sqrt{n} \cdot \sqrt{\dfrac{N-1}{N-n}}$$

Comment: The equality is false in general, and it's incorrect in several different ways at once. You're trying to produce an *estimate*, so the left hand side should not be $\sigma$. The scaling factor won't do what you need. What properties do you seek for an estimator of $\sigma$ to have? Are you simply trying to give a finite population correction?

Comment: That still looks wrong in at least two ways ... but it now looks even more like you're trying to do some kind of finite population correction. Please describe more accurately what you're trying to achieve. Why is $\sqrt n$ there?

Comment: Please, see again. I had changed the expression.

Comment: What's $\sqrt n$ for? Are you confusing $s$ with the usual sample estimate of the standard error of the mean?

Comment: My expression is derivated from the $$ \sigma_{\bar{X}} = \dfrac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}} \cdot \sqrt{\dfrac{N-n}{N-1}} $$ where i make $s =\sigma_{\bar{X}} $

Comment: But your question describes $s$ as "sample standard deviation". $\sigma_{\bar{X}}$ is the *standard error of a mean*. They're not things you can reasonably equate, since the first is dealing with individual observations and the second is dealing with sample means.

Comment: Now that I finally understand what you're doing, I can write an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's take the components one at a time.

- The $\sqrt{n}$ term would be appropriate if $s$ was the sample estimate of the standard error of the mean.

  However, you state $s$ to be the standard deviation, so that term doesn't belong.
- When the population is finite and the sample fraction isn't really small ($n/N$ isn't very small), the [finite population correction factor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_error#Correction_for_finite_population) is used to adjust the *standard error of a sample mean* for the fact that as $n$ samples (without replacement) a larger fraction of the population, the variance of the estimate reduces from the infinite-population form:

  $\hat{\sigma}_{\bar{X}}=\sqrt{\frac{N-n}{N-1}} \frac{s}{\sqrt{n}}$

  (So (i) you have it upside down and (ii) it shouldn't be there, since you're not esitmating $\hat{\sigma}_{\bar{X}}$). So we drop that term as well.
- If you want to estimate $\sigma$ itself - the standard deviation of the distribution of values rather than of means - you'd usually still just use $s$. If you want it to *exactly* equal $\sigma$ when $N=n$ you'd need to make an adjustment, but not that one (dropping the Bessel correction would work, for example).